# Why is parallel component of velocity along position vector considered rate of change of position?

Tags: kinematics, velocity, vectors, distance

If you have a position vector and a velocity vector of a particle, then the component of velocity vector along position vector is the rate of change of distance of the particle from the reference point of the vectors(say origin). Why is it so? I have included a picture (made a rough figure on notability and took a screenshot) that should make it easier to visualize my question.

It doesn't seem very intuitive to me. I do understand that the parallel component of velocity along position vector changes magnitude of the position vector but how is its magnitude also the rate of change of distance of particle or position vector from the origin? It should definitely bring in change in distance, but why is that rate of change equal to its magnitude? Hope I am not too confusing! Sorry if I am. [image]

Comment: My physics teacher just mentioned that in class. So what you are saying is that if I have two such vectors, the magnitude of velocity is itself the change of distance of position vector from origin?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question.

Comment: No problem. The way I have presented my question, it is easy to get confused, though I tried my best to prevent it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be understood in terms of vector differentiation and the dot product.  Take the example that $v \perp r$.  The change in the square of the displacement is 
$$\frac{d}{dt}r^2$$
$$=2r \cdot v$$, and if they are perpendicular, the dot product is zero.

Comment: Upvoted. One may also say that the motion of the point mass may be divided to the motion in the radial direction, and the motion in the transverse direction - which is locally the same thing as the angular direction "around" the center of coordinates. It's only the former that changes the distance - the distance isn't changing if we rotate around the circle - and it's only the former that contributes to the inner product.

Comment: Calculus and stuff is still a fancy term for me but I did understand the main core u were trying to explain.